# Extracting data from spark streaming dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm new to Spark Streaming.

I'm getting an event similar to below from Kafka. I have to extract the path from the dataframe, read the data from the path and write it to a destination.

```
{"path":["/tmp/file_path/file.parquet"],"format":"parquet","entries":null}
```

Any idea on how to extract the path and format the spark streaming dataframe?

Here's what I'm trying to achieve,

```
val df: DataFrame = spark.readStream.format("kafka").
    option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").
    option("subscribe", "kafka-test-event").
    option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()

  df.printSchema()
  val valDf = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
  val path = valDf.collect()(0).getString(0)
  println("path - "+ path)
  
  val newDf = spark.read.parquet(path)
  newDf.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").writeStream
    .format("console")
    .outputMode("append")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
kafka
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:374)
```

When I try to do a collect on the dataframe it throws an `Unsupported operation exception.`

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace. As written, this will only print the same JSON output, not parse anything (what have you tried to parse the `value` column that you've cast?)

Comment: i think it would make more sense to just use the StreamWriter to write your data to destination? but idk your use case

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes I trying to parse the value column. I have added the stacktrace.

Comment: `collect()` cannot be used on streaming datasets. Based on the fact that you're also trying to use Spark to read the paths in your events, you should use `spark.read.format("kafka")`. Then parquet isn't streaming dataset, so you use write, not writeStream

Comment: @OneCricketeer I was thinking of the same. I'll try doing that, Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are trying to do static operations on a streaming dataframe.

you can try something like below.
After you read the streaming dataframe from Kafka, try the below

1. Create a schema class for parsing the incoming data

   ```
   val incomingSchema = new StructType()
     .add("path", StringType)
     .add("format", StringType)
     .add("entries", StringType)
   ```
2. Associate that schema on top of incoming data and you can select the required fields from your data and do transformations on top of it.

   ```
   val valDf = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as jsonEntry").select(from_json($"jsonEntry",incomingSchema).select("path")
   ```

Comment: The path is an ArrayType

Comment: Select still returns a Dataframe. But I need the path as a string that I can use in spark.read

Comment: @BHC You need to combine `select` with `ForeachWriter` , to get each RDD batch from the dataframe, which you can then extract the field for each event to try to create a new dataframe (however, Spark might throw an error that you cannot nest your SparkSession in the executors)